# Why Emacs creates multiples whitespaces after I create a comment and jump to a new line?

Tags: indentation, whitespace, comment

I am using Emacs, Paredit, Slime to work on Common Lisp (SBCL). When I create a comment such as:

```lisp
; test
```

It is placed as expected. But if I press `return` in order to create a new line below `;test` this happens:

```lisp
                                        ; test
```

A bunch of whitespaces suddenly appear.

Why is this happening?

How can I avoid it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lisp has a more complex convention for comments than most languages, and automatic formatting respects this convention. It is documented in appendix [D.7 Tips on Writing Comments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Comment-Tips.html) of the Elisp manual (which is also available inside of Emacs itself, use `C-h i` to open the Info viewer).

In a nutshell, comments that start with just a `;` are formatted like marginal notes in a book; they go at the ends of the lines where the right–hand margin would be. Use `;;` for comments that are meant to be indented in a way similar to code; this puts the comments at the left–hand margin when they’re not inside a function or other type of top–level item. You can use `;;;` and `;;;;` for headings to divide your documentation or code up into sections and chapters.